# How do I activate syntax highlighting of an Xcode file template?

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting, xcode9, file-templates

I’m creating a file template for a file with an extension that Xcode doesn’t recognise. Xcode doesn’t apply syntax highlighting to the file but I’d like it to. I would like Xcode to recognise the file as `com.netscape.javascript-source` even though the file extension isn’t `.js` (the file is actually [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org)). I tried setting the `AllowedTypes` property of the `TemplateInfo.plist` to the UTI of JavaScript but that had no effect.

Alternatively, is it possible to define a new file extension for an existing UTI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on similar question.

It looks the only possible solution is to create a Cocoa Project that declares a new UTI.

Check those:

[How to make XCode recognize a custom file extension as Objective-C for syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050035/how-to-make-xcode-recognize-a-custom-file-extension-as-objective-c-for-syntax-hi)

[Adding syntax coloring to Xcode for unknown file extension such as ".tcl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961953/adding-syntax-coloring-to-xcode-for-unknown-file-extension-such-as-tcl)